# How to display json content with php?

Tags: php, json

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

function getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle($keyword) {
    $keywords = array();
    $data = file_get_contents('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=en-US&q='.urlencode($keyword));
    if (($data = json_decode($data, true)) !== null) {
        $keywords = $data[1];
    }

    return $keywords;
}

var_dump(getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('money'));
```

And it displays this on my page:

```
["money",["moneygram","money network","money mutual","moneypak","money saving mom","moneyball","money","money converter","money order","moneygram walmart"]]
```

What needs to make it display like this instead?

```
moneygram, money network, money mutual, moneypak, money saving mom, moneyball, money, money converter, money order, moneygram walmart
```

Comment: `echo implode(', ', getKeywordSuggestionsFromGoogle('money'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:
Use `json_decode` and then simply `implode` it

```
<?php
  $json_code = '["money",["moneygram","money network","money mutual","moneypak","money saving mom","moneyball","money","money converter","money order","moneygram walmart"]]';

  $data = json_decode($json_code);

  echo implode(',',$data[1]);
?>
```

This gives you output as:

```
moneygram, money network, money mutual, moneypak, money saving mom, moneyball, money, money converter, money order, moneygram walmart
```